# VS2013 fails to recognize added method for OCX control when building container application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, activex

I have a C++ native MFC Dialog app built with VS2013 that uses an OCX control built with VS2010.  I have a new upward compatible version of the OCX which has a new method in it.  I can't get VS2013 to recognize the new method for the OCX control.  The updated OCX is installed and I have even tried deleting the control in the dialog editor and then right clicking to **Insert ActiveX Control...**   I then add the OCX control back into the dialog selecting it from the list of registered OCX controls.  I have confirmed using **OLE-COM Object Viewer** that this new method is listed for the registered OCX control.

However VS2013 auto completion does not list the new method and when I try to compile the container app I get

DemoOCXDlg.cpp(441): error C2039: 'GetSigPlusVersionString' : is not a member of 'CSigPlus'

I noted that the CSigPlus OCX class defined in the auto generated OCX files "sigplus.h" and "sigplus.cpp" do not include the new method and that these files are not being regenerated to match the new implementation of the OCX control.  Is VS2013 supposed to regenerate these OCX description files automatically or is there some operation to do it manually?  Or were these files supposed to be created by VS2010 for the OCX project and copied to the container app project.  When I build the OCX project I'm not finding these computer generated files as outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The OCX definition files (ocx.h and ocx.cpp)
 are created via the Class Wizard in the container project.  Here's [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kdzetyx(v=vs.120).aspx) for the details on how to do it in VS2013

Comment: Don't just link to off-site content. In case the off-site resource becomes temporarily or permanently unavailable, this answer ceases to be useful. Instead, outline the essence of the linked content, and provide a link only for reference.

Comment: @Ilinspectable  I thought that's what I did.  "The OCX definition files (ocx.h and ocx.cpp) are created via the Class Wizard in the container project."  Also the link is to microsoft.com documentation so far less likely to become unavailable than most 3rd party links.